# X-path selector for grouping sibling nodes with same tags

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to build a web crawler using scrapy, that stores the data in a dictionary, where the keys are the text within the header(**h1**) tags and the values are the text in the **p** tags that follow the header tag.

Consider the following HTML code.

```
<h1>Heading1<h1>

<p> Some text </p>
<p> that </p>
<p> need to be</p>
<p> grouped </p>

<h1> Heading2 </h1>

<p> Another </p>
<p> few texts </p>
<p> that </p>
<p> need to be </p>
<p> grouped. </p>

<h1> Heading3 </h1>

<p> Same </p>
<p> here. </p>
```

How can I group all the p tags between h1 and return as a list using XPath selector(*version 1*).

for ex : ["Some texts that need to be grouped.",
"Another few texts that need to be grouped."
"Same here."
]

OR

Is there a better logic to approach the problem?

Any help appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using XPath-1.0 alone. But you can use an XSLT approach (which applies XPath-1.0 functions). This does group your output as desired. So apply this XSLT-1.0 stylesheet to your XML data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="head" match="*[not(self::h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1])" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:for-each select="h1">
            <group>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('head', generate-id())">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group> Some text  that  need to be grouped </group>
<group> Another  few texts  that  need to be  grouped. </group>
<group> Same  here. </group>
```

Now you can import this XML data into Python (It may be necessary to wrap that data into a root element so that it becomes palatable to an XML parser). But now you can extract each group as a string value of an element named `<group>`.

**P.S.:**
If you want to get rid of unnecessary spaces, change the `xsl:value-of` to

```
<xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
```

Comment: I do not know much about XSLT, but I will surely check it out. Thank you for the quick response and sharing your thoughts. This could help me get some progress on my project.